# Gigagbyte board with Intel i211 nic wont wake up on network access, on on WOL magic packet

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, wake-on-lan

All my machines running identical Windows 10 setups wake on lan access. This means, I can send SMB, HTTP of RDP requests and they wake up. Then, this one Gigabyte board, only wakes on a WOL magic packet.

I cant imagine Intel screwed up their i211 nic. I doubt Gigabyte did the same (though this is an Aurus board and the BIOS leaves much to be desired).

What could it be?

Comment: Are the others with the same NIC and the same board? It is possible that the Gigabyte board only supports magic packets. Can you check this somehow?

Comment: No, the others do not have same board or nic.

Comment: @InquisitorShm, did you manage to get WoL working on your board. I have an Aorus Pro with the same issue.

Comment: Yes. It will not wake up with a packet directed to it attempting to open a port (like SSH or RDP or HTTP ports). Instead, you have to craft an actual WOL packet and send it to the mac - its the only way.